# Which of these two have higher performance: ODBC Connection or SQL Connection?

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, sqlconnection

I have an application which Uses Fedex API integration. the application is using ODBC Connection to connect to the SQL Server.It's large data and takes long time to fetch data and perform the operation. 
Is there can be any change in performance if I Use SQL connection?
In simple , which of the two have faster performance?

ODBC:

```
      OdbcConnection Conn2 = new OdbcConnection();
      Conn2.ConnectionString = @"Dsn=Excel Files;dbq=" + lFileName + ";driverid=1046;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5";
```

SQL:

```
      Sqlconnection con=new Sqlconnection ();
      con.ConnectionString ="Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
                             User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

Comment: Have you notice any difference in performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're asking if the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC is faster than using the native SQL Server provider, rather than asking if the ODBC driver for SQL Server is faster than the .NET Provider for SQL Server.

Generally, you'll likely find that using the native provider for a database will be faster than using the .NET ODBC Provider because the .NET ODBC Provider is wrapping an ODBC driver, so it needs to make native calls on the ODBC driver. In addition, one function call on the .NET ODBC Provider may map to multiple calls in the underlying ODBC driver that will introduce additional overhead. The native provider can write directly to the wire using the SQL Server wire protocol, avoiding overhead from the ODBC driver.

As always, your mileage may vary and you should always perform a simple test to validate.